# In sbt, how do I create a source dependency on a branch of a local git repository?

Tags: scala, sbt

sbt has these syntaxes for source dependency projects:

```
RootProject(file("/a/b/c"))
RootProject(uri("git://github.com/a/b/c#some-branch"))
```

But I can't find any way to clone from a local git repository which doesn't require something ridiculous like running a git server. I would like to express the following, or a moral equivalent - moral equivalency means it should not require ssh or working DNS or a git server or even working resolution of "localhost", nor should it introduce any form of pointless build fragility. (Manually checking out the desired branch into another working dir and pointing sbt at that is an example of pointless build fragility.)

```
RootProject(file("/a/b/c#some-branch"))
// This seems like the most plausible syntax,
// but it explodes during cloning - "ssh: Could not resolve hostname git"
RootProject(uri("git:/a/b/c#some-branch"))
```

Comment: Just in case: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1152

Comment: 'Also the "file/git/url" projects are something We're planning to rethink slightly in the face of "sbt-server".' Wonderful, I'll enjoy these few seconds during which it works before they deprecate it so I can learn a new edifice of scopes, axes, configurations, and natures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second try was very close, assuming that `commit` is the SHA1 of the commit you want to use and you cloned the repo to `/a/b/c`:

```
RootProject(uri(s"git:file:///a/b/c/#$commit"))
```

Comment: I asked the question not actually thinking it was possible. Well done sir! May I ask: is this documented somewhere which eluded me, or did you intuit it, or did you read the source?

Comment: Sometime ago I wanted to do this too, so I asked on #scala, where somebody pointed me to this solution